# Creating table when each object may have a list of values

Tags: sql, postgresql

First I've created a table with information on stores and transactions with the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE main.store_transactions
(
   store_id                      varchar(100)   NOT NULL,
   store_name                    varchar(100),
   store_transaction_id          varchar(100),
   transaction_name              varchar(100),
   transaction_date              timestamp,
   transaction_info              varchar(200),
   primary_key(store_id)
)
```

But then I realized that the same store may have various transactions related to it, not just one. How should I implement table creation in this case?

One thing that comes to mind is to create a separate table with transactions, each transaction having store_id as a foreign key. And then just join when needed. 
How is it possible to implement it in a single table?

Comment: You don't want to implement two entities in a single table.  Stores are not transactions, that's why you want two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the most elegant way would be indeed to create a satelite table for your `stores` and reference it to the `store_transactions` table, e.g:

```
CREATE TABLE stores
(
   store_id         varchar(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   store_name       varchar(100)
);

CREATE TABLE store_transactions
(
   store_id              varchar(100) NOT NULL REFERENCES stores(store_id),
   store_transaction_id  varchar(100),
   transaction_name      varchar(100),
   transaction_date      timestamp,
   transaction_info      varchar(200)       
);
```

With this structure you will have *many* transactions to a single store.

There are other less appealing options, such as customizing a data type for `stores` and creating an array of it in the table `store_transactions`. But regarding the costly maintainability of such approach, I would definitely discourage it.